# How to create this Multidimensional Array with this query (That eventually turns into JSON)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have done my research. But after 2 days I'm going crazy. I really want to avoid sending multiple queries to MYSQL. I understand that the solution is iterating and inserting the values in the new array. But honestly I does not know where to start. this Multidimensional array I want to create is out of my league. 
Thanks!

I need to turn the following MYSQL Result:

```
    categories  subcategories   items
    ----------  -------------   ------
    ART       painter        picasso
    ART       painter        VanGogh
    ART       sculpture      Rodin
    ART       sculpture      Serra
    MUSIC     Rock           Lennon
    MUSIC     Rock           Mercury
    MUSIC     Classic        Mozart
    THEATRE   Drama          Shakespeare
    THEATRE   Drama          Moliere
```

Into This PHP Array:

```
 $Data = array (
    name=>'ARTISTS', 
    children=>array(
        array('name'=>'ART', 
                children=>array(
        array('name'=>'Painting', children=>array(array('name'=>'picasso'),array('name'=>'Van Gogh'))),
        array('name'=>'Sculpture', children=>array(array('name'=>'Rodin'),array('name'=>'Serra')))
        )),
        array('name'=>'MUSIC', 
                children=>array(
        array('name'=>'Rock', children=>array(array('name'=>'Lennon'),array('name'=>'Mercury'))),
        array('name'=>'Classic', children=>array(array('name'=>'Mozart')))
        )),
        array('name'=>'THEATRE', 
                children=>array(
        array('name'=>'Drama', children=>array(array('name'=>'Shakespeare'),array('name'=>'Moliere')))
        ))
    )
);
```

The only thing I know is that this PHP array (written manually) generate a perfect JSON once you pass it through json_encode.  So this last part is not the problem. I just put it here to explain where all this is going.

```
$json = json_encode($Data);
```

Generates:

```
{"name":"ARTISTS","children":[{"name":"ART","children":[{"name":"Painting","children":[{"name":"picasso"},{"name":"Van Gogh"}]},{"name":"Sculpture","children":[{"name":"Rodin"},{"name":"Serra"}]}]},{"name":"MUSIC","children":[{"name":"Rock","children":[{"name":"Lennon"},{"name":"Mercury"}]},{"name":"Classic","children":[{"name":"Mozart"}]}]},{"name":"THEATRE","children":[{"name":"Drama","children":[{"name":"Shakespeare"},{"name":"Moliere"}]}]}]}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the 'children' field in the json... it seems a bit bulky.  but that said and done, what do you have already and how is it not working?

Comment: The reason why I need it like this:    http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

Comment: I do have the structure, what I dont know how to do, is to turn my  MYSQL results into that PHP array.

Answer (score 1):

I would scrap the notion of applying all those unneccesary `name` and `children` labels.  When you get your database result set, just iterate through it and set all array index items directly.

```
$data = array();
while ($row = /*  your DB row fetch here */) {
    $data[$row['categories']][$row['subcategories']][] = $row[$items];
}

$json_data = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I know is unnecessary, but this is the format I'll been asked to deliver the jason. :/

Comment: Woow, super clean, I tried and definitely is the best way to go, however I'm dealing with a D3 implemetation that require this specific format to read the information: Visit:   http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

Answer (score 0):

As `Mike Brant` said, you should use names of your categories as indexes. But if you still need a solution that would give a result like you gave, here is some code:

```
$formatted = array() ;

foreach($data as $part){
    if (!array_key_exists($part['categories'], $formatted)){
        $formatted[$part['categories']] = array(
            "name" => $part['categories'],
            "children" => array()
        );
    }

    $sub = &$formatted[$part['categories']]['children'] ;

    if (!array_key_exists($part['subcategories'], $sub)){
        $sub["name"] = $part['subcategories'] ;
        $sub["children"] = array() ;
    }

    $items = &$sub['children'] ;

    $items[$part['items']] = array("name"=>$part['items']) ;
}

print_r($formatted);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, still it is not coming out as JSON arrays (square Bracketts) and is nesting in a different format.  The output I'm trying to achieve is for a D3 implementation that require this specific format:   http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550     thanks again!